# Should i normalized or de-normalized this database?

Tags: database, database-design

Creating a database for a machine ( which has up to 25-30 parts each ). so my machine table will contain at least 30-35 columns or maybe more.But not every machine contains all the parts some of them has only 3-4 parts.

I have to perform multiple views, add, edit, and updates so I want thinking about normalizing the database.

So which is the efficient way to handle this database? Should I go for normalized or de-normalized?

Comment: If you have to ask, then the answer is always "normalized".  *Always.*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without examples, but based on what you've said, it sounds like you need something like:

```
Machine
    ID
    Name
    etc.

Part
   ID
   Name
   etc.

Machine_Parts
    Machine_ID       -- FK into Machine
    Part_ID          -- FK into Part
```

Now one Part can be in multiple Machines, and a Machine can have multiple Parts.

I understand the appeal for having all the Parts listed in the Machine record, but consider that if you add a new Part, you have a database structure change.  If you have a Parts table you just add a new Part and you're done.

Comment: Let's take an example of a user building custom car. I have parts (1st table 60000+ entry) table, and now user can pick any parts, and that will be added to his car ( 2nd table ).

Comment: So each record in the Machine table is a separate customized car?